# Зафиксировать ближайшую дату в начале списка, далее вывести список по убыванию даты

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть модель `Task`, в ней атрибут `date` (тип данных `date`) который пользователь выбирает при заполнении формы, в формате "2016-05-28".

Как сделать список (`@task.each do` и т.д.), в котором объекты `Task` с наиближайшей выбранной пользователем датой показывались бы наверху (и далее по убывающей)?

Answer (score 1):

Если модель унаследована от базового класса ActiveRecord и поддерживает методы ActiveRecord, отсортировать вывод можно при помощи метода `order`

```
@tasks = Task.order(start_at: :desc)
@tasks.each do |task|
...
```

В старых версиях Ruby on Rails, не поддерживающих такой синтаксис, возможно потребуется явно записать строку сортировки

```
@tasks = Task.order('start_at DESC')
@tasks.each do |task|
...
```

Для того, чтобы извлечь ближайшую дату, можно выполнить запрос вида

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  tasks
ORDER BY
  ABS(start_at - NOW())
LIMIT 1
```

Далее полученный идентификатор ближайшей записи можно использовать для того, чтобы поместить его первым. Пусть `id` = 2

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tasks
ORDER BY
  IF(id = 2, 0, 1), start_at DESC
```

Объединив два запроса можно получить следующий

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tasks
ORDER BY
  IF(id = (SELECT
             id
           FROM
             tasks
           ORDER BY
            ABS(created - NOW()) LIMIT 1), 0, 1),
  start_at DESC
```

В результате ближайшая запись будет зафиксирована первой, а после нее пойдут все остальные записи. Теперь можно перевести полученный запрос в ActiveRecord

```
order_by = 'IF(id = (SELECT
             id
            FROM
              tasks
            ORDER BY
             ABS(created - NOW()) LIMIT 1), 0, 1),
            start_at DESC'
@tasks = Task.order(order_by)
@tasks.each do |task|
```

Лучше, конечно, на уровне модели организовать `scope`

```
scope :ordered, -> {
  order_by = 'IF(id = (SELECT
               id
              FROM
                tasks
              ORDER BY
               ABS(created - NOW()) LIMIT 1), 0, 1),
              start_at DESC'
  order(order_by)
}
```

Тогда обращаться к модели можно будет следующим образом

```
@tasks = Task.all.ordered
@tasks.each do |task|
...
```

Comment: Pro tip: если использовать heredoc с пометкой `SQL`, редактор может даже синтаксис подсветить (снято в Sublime Text): http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/16/0528/h_1464466923_6326320_1e4723f1db.png